# ECS/Fargate container definition command arguments

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, docker-run

We are trying to start a fargate container on AWS ECS. In the container definition we have

```
"command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        "\"envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'\""
      ]
```

I also tried:

```
"command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
      ]
```

Using `docker run`, we would successfully use:

```
docker run -p 8000:80 -e "VAR1=somevalue" -d nginx-sample:latest /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

And in kubernetes world (which also works):

```
 containers:
      env:
      - name: VAR1
        value: "somevalue"
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c", "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

We cannot get this to work so far in AWS Fargate. It's not clear to me how we should pass the arguments in a valid way. The containers appear to exit before being able to start but there are no obvious log messages, so it's not entirely clear why. I think it's something I'm doing wrong with the syntax in the way the command arguments to `/bin/bash -c` are being passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end the right syntax (well at least one that worked well for us) was:

```
"command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
      ],
```

Our real issue actually turned out to be that we had defined a container health check along the lines of:

```
"healthCheck": {
        "retries": 5,
        "command": [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl --fail http://localhost/health || exit 1"
        ],
        "timeout": 10,
        "interval": 30,
        "startPeriod": 30
      },
```

And we forgot to verify that `curl` was actually installed inside the container. We took it for granted that it'd be there, but in the `nginx:latest` image, it is not - I presume rightly so for smaller size and smaller attack surface as an exploit vector. We ended up just installing curl in our `Dockerfile`, after that all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

```
"entryPoint": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c"
      ],
"command": [
        "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
      ],
```

This worked for us when we had to do something like this.

In our case, we used `entryPoint` to force the container to ignore the **base image** command. Then gave an additional command in `command` arry.

If not I believe, ECS uses base image `CMD`(`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`) and run anything in `command` array on top of that. I'm just speculating this; as I can't make sense why the other way just don't work.